# Django seems not to run on port 8000

Tags: django, windows, port, connection-refused

I am working on a project linking django (for backend) and React (for frontend)
It worked perfeclty for 5 months and then this morning, when I run django (`python manage.py runserver`), I cannot access to the django server.
First, my frontend tells me he can't have an access to it:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/token/refresh/ from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

Then I try to type `127.0.0.1:8000` in my browser's navbar, in order to access the django admin (as I used to do, until this morning) and my browser tells me that localhost refuses connection.

Finally, I typed `netstat -aon | find /i "listening"` in my cmd and the list did not include port 8000

I don't know what to do and when I type "django does not run on port 8000" on the Internet, I cannot find a satisfying answer.

Could someone help me?

(edit): Ok I follow someone advice on another subject comment and I had to restart my computer (not stopping it and then starting it, but restarting it).
I don't know why but it works.
I put here the link for this answer in order to reference that person: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46967320/16349513

Comment: did you check if _runserver_ with **<port_number>** works, like: `python manage.py runserver 8000`

Comment: I just tried and it does not work either

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a mac?

In that case:

1. make sure to use sudo lsof -i tcp:8000
2. afterwards kill the process ids that show up

Try that.